# How to open applications after booting a purely Command line interface?

Tags: command-line

After booting linux in purely command line mode how can I open an application eg web browser or Libre Office?

For example if I use the command "play" with any audio file it starts to play it. I want to know commands for other applications.

Answer (score 0):

you find all "possible" commands by taking a look into the folder your PATH includes...

Type "ls `echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'`" to get a list of ALL commands that your PATH includes...

if you want to execute something special you should think about the name of the binary, for example: firefox

type "which firefox" to see where it is stored...: /usr/bin/firefox

and if an application is NOT in the PATH you can execute it with the full command: /path/to/your/binary if it has the execution flag ('x')

Answer (score 0):

#### Text-based web browsers:

There are some text based web browsers that you can use to browse the web and view the offline web pages. e.g.

- [`links2`](http://links.twibright.com)

  *Installation:*

  ```
  sudo apt-get install links2
  ```

  (before installation make sure Universe repo is allowed.)
- `lynx`

  *Installation:*

  ```
  sudo apt-get install lynx
  ```
- `w3m`

  *Installation:*

  ```
  sudo apt-get install w3m
  ```

---

You can use the *document* to *text or HTML* conversion utilities to convert the document files and view with CLI *text editors* or *web browsers*.

#### Document to text/html conversion tools:

- `catdoc` converts `*.doc` document files to text files.

  *Installation:*

  ```
  sudo apt-get install catdoc
  ```

  This program extracts text from MS-Word files, trying to preserve as many special printable characters as possible. catdoc supports everything up to
  Word-97.
- `poppler-utils` provides various CLI tools to manipulate PDF documents, some of which are `pdftohtml` - PDF to HTML converter, `pdftotext` - text extraction.

  *Installation:*

  ```
  sudo apt-get install poppler-utils
  ```

---

But if you have *LibreOffice* installed to your system, you can use it for file conversion (format export) too. For this use:

```
libreoffice --invisible output_file_extension[:output_filter_name] [--outdir output_dir] file...
```

*(the parameters within square brackets [...] are optional)*

e.g.

Conversion to *text* file:

```
libreoffice --invisible --convert-to txt:Text --outdir /home/hash/Desktop /home/hash/Documents/hashDoc.odt
```

Conversion to *HTML* file:

```
libreoffice --invisible --convert-to html --outdir /home/hash/Desktop /home/hash/Documents/hashDoc.odt
```

Conversion to *PDF* file:

```
libreoffice --invisible --convert-to pdf --outdir /home/hash/Desktop /home/hash/Documents/hashDoc.odt
```

*(plug-ins should be pre-installed.)*

Comment: ..for more information about usage of a command you can use the `commandname --help` or view manpage documentation with `man commandname`